# Can my cousin visit me on a family visit visa when I am not a UK resident?

Tags: visas, uk

I am in UK on a Business Visit Visa for 6 months. I want to invite my cousin who studies in Germany to the UK.

Should I ask her to apply for a "Family Visit Visa" or a "General Visit Visa" ?

I do not have UK Citizenship.

Comment: What is your cousin's citizenship? That probably matters more than anything.

Comment: If your cousin is a visa-national, she would apply for a general VV.  Based upon what you wrote, you do not qualify as a sponsor in the first instance.

Comment: Close voters: What's unclear about this question? Seems pretty clear to me; the question that I edited the title to seems pretty cut and dried, and the top answer reflects that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the Family Visit Visa is an option for 2 reasons, based on the published [eligibility requirements](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa/eligibility).

**Reason 1:  Ineligible family relationship**

The list of people who can be visited under a Family visa is given as:

- spouse or civil partner
- children
- parents or siblings
- grandparents or
  grandchildren
- your spouse’s or civil partner’s siblings or parents
- your child’s spouse or civil partner
- step parents, step children or step siblings
- a person you've been living with in a long-term relationship, as if you were married or in a civil partnership, for at least 2 years before the day you apply

A cousin is none of those things.

**Reason 2: Ineligible residency status**

The family member being visited must be one of:

- a British citizen
- settled in the UK
- granted asylum in the UK
- under humanitarian protection in the UK

You're not a British citizen, and I don't think being in the UK on a short-term visa yourself counts as being "settled in the UK". The other 2 options are presumably not relevant either.

Comment: To confirm:  The op is not settled in the UK; otherwise they would not need a BVV.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/short-visit-visas
The Family Visitor visa is intended for visits of 6 months. If your cousin is studying in Germany I suspect she won't be coming for that long.

If it's just a simple visit then General Visitor visa appears to be the correct one.

Comment: A general visitor visa is good for up to 6 months too, so that doesn't really serve to differentiate them.  More to the point is that as far as I can see the OP & their cousin are simply not eligible for  the Family visa.

Comment: @NigelHarper My reading of the immigration website is that the Family Visa is required for a visit of *more than* six months, precisely because a General (tourist) visa does not have sufficient duration. For less than six months a Gereral visa is all that is required and the purpose being to visit family is irrelevant.

Comment: I've no idea how you manage to read it that way.  It clearly says "You can stay in the UK for 6 months on a Family Visitor visa." There's nothing to indicate you can stay for over 6 months.

Comment: @NigelHarper The page I linked to doesn't say that, it says "Apply for a Family Visitor visa if you want to come to the UK to visit a family member for 6 months". The link to the FVV from that page says "You can apply to extend your visa up to 6 months if it’s for less than 6 months." (That seems to me a very clear indication that you *can* stay for longer.) This ability to extend the FVV does NOT apply to the General visa, with which "You can stay for a maximum of 6 months on each visit".

Comment: My original quote is from the [FVV overview](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa/overview).

Also look at [Extend your visa](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa/extend-your-visa) for the FVV. Under How Long Can You Stay it says: "You can stay in the UK for 6 months on a Family Visitor visa.

You can apply to extend your visa up to 6 months if it’s for less than 6 months."

As I read that you can apply for an FVV with the stated plan to stay for, say 3 months, but change your mind once in the UK and extend up to 6 months from date of entry.  You can't go beyond 6 months on an FVV.

Comment: Also you can apply to [extend a General visa](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/extend-your-visa) - but again only a visa that was for < 6 months up to a total of 6 months.

Comment: OK, fair enough. All of which seems IMHO to make the existence of the FVV completely pointless.

Comment: I agree it's not immediately obvious - I think the main difference may be that the circumstances of the "sponsor" are taken into account for the FVV with regards to support (e.g. free/subsidised board and lodgings) so the visitor may not need to show they have as much cash. It's not terribly clear though.